# Numbers in Strings comparisons over '1000' giving strange results

Tags: javascript, numbers

I was comparing attribute values from iframes earlier, and before using `parseInt()` was interested to find that numbers in strings *over* 1000 prove false to numbers less than themselves when tested in a "greater than" comparison:

```
'1000' > '900' // false
'901' > '900' // true
```

Why is this? Of course, using parseInt is just fine:

```
1000 > 900 // true
901 > 900 // true
```

Comment: Because strings compared as (sic!) strings.

Comment: If you ever want an incredibly formal, authoritative description of how comparison works in Javascript, see the [ECMAScript standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.5). Warning: it can be very hard to read.

Comment: Strings are compared [lexiographically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are ordered alphabetically, and 1 is before 9 in the alphabet.

Comment: Nit: neither 1 or 9 are in the [English] alphabet - the ordering is defined according to another reference xD

Answer (score 1):

This is because, there is character comparison happening here. This happens based on ASCII code of the charater (http://www.asciitable.com/)

As you can see on the link - ASCII code of 1 (49 or 0x30) < ASCII code of 9 (57 or 0x39) . Hence `'1000' < '900'`.

This is why: `"abc" < "xyz"`

Comment: Strictly speaking it's based on 16-bit Unicode encoding, but that's the same as ASCII in the low 7-bit range.

Comment: @Pointy, I assumed that ASCII will be easier to comprehend with for the original poster :-) But yes, you are right.